# Selecting all checkboxes and storing the names of selected checkbox in session. PHP,Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, session

I have a checkbox list generated using php depending upon number of coloumns in database,
for each checkbox i'm using a onchange function to store it's name in session variable if it' checked.
In order to select all checkbox i'm using a javascript....but in that way i'm not able to send checkboxes name to session.
How can i select all checkboxes at a time as well as store their names in session variable(only checked ones name must go out of all)??

Comment: Are you using AJAX function in onchange?

Comment: Please show us some code so we can suggest something.

Comment: yes i'm using ajax function, for each function call checkbox id is received and value is sent to a php file to add it's value to session.

Comment: Displaying Checkbox list (http://pastebin.com/7WVfYKxn)

Comment: Ajax to store checkbox name in session(http://pastebin.com/TBWarNB2Q)

Comment: Personally, i'd be storing this in a cookie. Still readable by php, but this way, javascript can add to it. Use serialize or json_encode()/json_decode() to store arrays.

Comment: nick i'm not familiar with json....!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You are using AJAX function call on `onChange=""` then you must be executing a single function every time you click on a checkbox and setting a session variable, in that function you may place this conditionally like

> **UPDATE:**

```
if (particular checkbox is checked/Unchecked?){
        if(select all checkbox is checked?){
             //send ajax request to php file to unset that particular session, as in this case all check box will be checked
         }else{
             //send ajax request to php file to set that particular session
         }

}elseif(select all checkbox is checked?){
   //send ajax request to php file to set all the checkbox sessions
}
```

Comment: in case if after selecting all checkbox one or two checkbox is unchecked thn how i've to proceed??

Comment: even in later case when all checkbox are selected i've to write id of all checkbox myself while if i use onchange function for each single request id of checkbox is obtained from this.id

Comment: in this case are you unchecking the Select All checkbox?

Comment: leave that thing OM for that case my onchange function is still working if i uncheck any 1 of those.finally the problem is reduced to i have field list in an array and when i check select all i've to call the javascript function for each value in array. kind of apply()

Comment: Yes true you are going correct and at the next if u unselect any one of the checkbox that particular session for checkbox must get unset or set to empty or set to '0'

Comment: can you help me with elseif(select all checkbox is checked?){
   //send ajax request to php file to set all the checkbox sessions
}to send ajax request i still need all the id's how i'm gonna send all those id's or another option is to call the javascript function for each value in array.i'm not gtng how to call function for an array or send the id's to ajax function

Comment: You dont have to send all ids in function, You just have to send the selectall checkbox's id, if its is found checked then in php file set all the available checkboxes sessions

Comment: Got you.let me try dis and reply you if i get it done.Thanks a lot anewaz. :)